# Largest neighborhood on which $f(z)=\sum\limits_{p\text{ prime}} z^p$ defines an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Find the largest $r$ such that
$$f(z) = \sum\limits_{p\text{ prime}}z^p$$
defines an analytic function on $B_r(0).$

The series diverges for $|z|\geq 1$, since the terms don't go to zero, and converges absolutely for $|z|<1$ by comparison with the geometric series, so I think the answer is $r=1$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right; if $r$ is the radius of convergence of the series, then 
$$\frac{1}{r}=\lim\sup |a_n|^{1/n}.$$
Here $a_n$ is either $0$ or $1$, so in the supremum, we consider only those $a_n$'s which are equal to $1$, so $\frac{1}{r}=1$.

Comment: This is called the Hadamard radius formula .